# Translating a math book written in plain TeX into Swedish - problem with accented characters

Tags: math-mode, languages, accents

I'm translating a wellknown calculus book into Swedish. The source code is plain TeX and is of course littered with commands, macros and what not that won't work in LaTeX. I need to be able to use the Swedish accented characters (åäöÅÄÖé) and know of {\aa} {\"a] ...

It would be easy to search and replace if it were not for the fact that {\aa}, for instance, gives TeX hiccups in math mode. This is a looong book which will take me four months of intense labor to translate, and there will be tens of thousands of accented characters in math mode. I would dearly love not to have to do any more work than I have to.

Is there some (easy or at least semi-easy) way that I can get these accented characters to work? Is rewriting the source into LaTeX form the best (only?) option, or is there some magic that can be done?

Comment: `\aa` used in math mode? It doesn't work in Plain TeX.

Comment: It's been two decades since I used TeX, but things like this seemed to do the trick (at least in the first chapter...): \catcode`\ä=\active
\def ä{\ifmmode\hbox{\"a}\else{\"a}\fi}
I'm sure the \hbox in math mode will look ugly as hell, but I'm only interested in proof reading at this stage.

Comment: Save your document as UTF-8 and load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Or use one of the engines that use Unicode by default, such as Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX.  In this particular case, I believe that's the only sensible option (especially since it's a book to be written in an entirely different language).

Comment: The direct use of the `ä` character in math mode is, shall we say, unusual. In math/physics contexts, a double-dot accent above a letter generally denotes the second derivative of the variable with respect to time, and the spacing of these dots usually differs from that used for typographic umlauts. Try `\ddot{a}` instead.

Comment: There are rather few plain tex commands that don't work in latex, the `plain` package anyway redefines most of the remaining missing ones. As other commentators have said markup of accented letters in math is pretty much the same in plain and latex (why do you need to change from plain to latex anyway? Another option is just to leave it as plain)